# How to right-align form input boxes?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a seemingly easy problem to solve, but am struggling. How do I get these two inputs to align to the right of the form, without using the BR element ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    form {
        text-align: right;
    }
    input {
        width: 100px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
         <input name="declared_first" value="above" />

         <br/> <!-- I want to get rid of this -->

         <input name="declared_second" value="below" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want the first input to appear above the second input, both on the right hand side.

Comment: How does the `br` element cause alignment?

Comment: Wrap the inputs in block elements like divs

Comment: Those inputs need labels. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use floating to the right and clear them.

```css
form {
  overflow: hidden;
}
input {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="declared_first" value="above" />
  <input name="declared_second" value="below" />
</form>
```

You can also set a right-to-left `direction` to the parent and restore the default left-to-right on the inputs. With `display: block` you can force them to be on different lines.

```css
form {
  direction: rtl;
}
input {
  display: block;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="declared_first" value="above" />
  <input name="declared_second" value="below" />
</form>
```

Or the modern way, flexbox layout

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="declared_first" value="above" />
  <input name="declared_second" value="below" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ah, nice. Cheers. I actually solved it by making the form narrower (and giving it a left margin). Deffo worth knowing though - thanks.

Comment: @cullub Clearance prevents the inputs from stacking horizontally, this way each one is in a different line. Adding a non-floated element with clearance after the inputs or using `overflow:hidden` on the container may also be a good idea to force it to grow enough to wrap the inputs.

Answer (score 21):

Try use this:

```
<html>
<body>
   <input type="text" style="direction: rtl;" value="1">
   <input type="text" style="direction: rtl;" value="10">
   <input type="text" style="direction: rtl;" value="100">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is quite ingenious.  Works perfectly with bootstrap.  +1

Comment: Except for negative numbers and floats.

Answer (score 6):

```
input { float: right; clear: both; }
```

Comment: Floated elements do not need `display: block;`. [CSS Float Theory: Things You Should Know](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/): "All floats become a block box; the standard says that the display property is to be ignored for floats, unless it’s specified as none". The article goes on to point back to `display: inline;` as an IE fix, but outside of that (and past IE7) `display` does nothing.

Comment: Awesome - had forgotten this. Fixed my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    p {
        text-align: right;
    }
    input {
        width: 100px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <p>
            <input name="declared_first" value="above" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input name="declared_second" value="below" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

To affect ONLY text type input boxes use the attribute selector

input[type="text"]

This way it will not affect other inputs and just text inputs.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

example, use a div and give it an idea to refer to:

```
#divEntry input[type="text"] {
text-align: right;}
```

Comment: So simple! Thank you for posting this! I just added class="text-right" to my bootstrap input and wallah.

Answer (score 2):

Use some  tag, to aligning the input element. 
So

```
<form>
   <div>
     <input>
     <br />
     <input>
    </div>
</form>

    .mydiv
     {
        width: 500px;
        height: 250px;
        display: table;
        text-align: right;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question in a blog post: https://wscherphof.wordpress.com/2015/06/17/right-align-form-elements-with-css/
It refers to this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wscherphof/9sfcw4ht/9/

Spoiler: `float: right;` is the right direction, but it takes just a little more attention to get neat results.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
input {
  clear: both;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
```