# How do I right align form buttons under an object?

Tags: html, css, forms, button, alignment

My question is similiar to other questions I've researched on StackOverflow, the closest one being here:  [How to right-align form input boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114966/how-to-right-align-form-input-boxes)

However, the suggested solution does not work, in my instance.  For some reason, no matter what sort of formatting I use, I cannot get the inline form buttons to align to the right below the object I've embedded.

My structure is a page overlay for an agreement that users will either click 'I Accept' to (handled to not show the agreement again with a cookie), or 'Cancel' to take them back to the homepage.

However, underneath the object, the form buttons want to either stay left-aligned, go into a left-aligned column, or disappear when I use float: right.  Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Display a form in a lightbox</title>
<style>
  #overlay{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.75;
    opacity:.75;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
  }

  #popup{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    bottom: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    margin:auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid c9c9c9;
    background-color: f7f7f7;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  form {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
  }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="popup">
  <object type="text/html" data="#link to embedded page" width="60%" height="90%" style="overflow: auto">
  </object><br>
  <form>
<input id="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"/>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="I Agree" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Here's a screenshot of the alignment:

https://copy.com/QpqzPFkmDqpxk14p

I much appreciate any help on the issue, thanks!

Comment: Please remove the JavaScript and any other irrelevant code from your question. Ideally, include the remainder in a snippet so we can see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Div tag and form to look like the following.

```
  <div id="popup">

        <object type="text/html" data="#reference to forum rules page" width="60%" height="90%" style="overflow: auto">
  </object><br>



         <form action="#reference to homepage" method="get">
           <div align="right">
              <input id="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" />

              <input id="submit" type="submit" value="I Agree" />
            </div>
         </form>

      </div>
```

You don't need to use 2 form elements, one form element with both inputs in it.

Comment: If I do that, will both buttons go to the homepage?  I only want 'cancel' to take users to the homepage, and 'I agree' to let users view the page they're on normally, without the overlay.  Thanks for responding, I will test it out and see what the results are! :)

Comment: Combining the forms works with the edits I made thanks to your suggestion. :)

However, concerning the alignment, right align pulls the embedded page object to halfway off the page with the buttons nowhere in sight (either disappeared or aligned properly, but with the whole div now aligned wrong).  Just a note, when I embed another div inside the current div to align just the form buttons, they disappear.  ...case of the disappearing buttons :p   Is there some creative formatting I can use to re-center the div containing the object with the 'align=right' attribute?  Thanks!

Comment: I solved it just by repositioning:      

    #popup{
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 10%;
        bottom: 10%;
        left: -40%;
        right: 0%;