# CSS Align Span to right of list?

Tags: css

## HTML

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item normal-row">TEST TEXT <span class="cross">✘</span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item normal-row">TEST TEXT <span class="rtr_symbolcross"><span class="tick">✔</span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item normal-row">TEST TEXT TEST TEXT TEST TEXT<span class="cross">✘</span></li>
    <li class="list-group-item normal-row">TEST TEXT TEST TEXT<span class="tick">✔</span></li>
</ul>
```

## CSS

```
.tick {
    text-align: right;
}
.cross {
    text-align: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ewgp3oxL/

How can I make the above, look like:

[image]

So as you can see the ticks and crosses are all the way over at the right hand side, the css that I've tried does nothing to :S

I'm using a span because I also apply color, background color, font-size, font-weight,  shadow... and some other stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to right-align form input boxes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12114966/1529630)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change span position to absolute and right to 0px.

Here you can change the space between the cross/tick and the text.

```
li{
    position:relative;
    width:600px;
}
.cross, .tick {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
}
```

[JSFidle](https://jsfiddle.net/ewgp3oxL/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Use float instead of text-align

```
.tick {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
.cross {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

Working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/1xmxncLr/

Answer (score 2):

For a flexbox approach.

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item normal-row">TEST TEXT <span class="cross">✘</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item normal-row">TEST TEXT <span class="rtr_symbolcross"><span class="tick">✔</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item normal-row">TEST TEXT TEST TEXT TEST TEXT<span class="cross">✘</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item normal-row">TEST TEXT TEST TEXT<span class="tick">✔</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) is used to align content within its parent so, in this instance, it would try to align the ticks & crosses to the right of the spans which, as they are inline elements and will only be as wide as their content, will produce no visual change.

Flexbox would have been my preferred solution but, as Paulie_D already covered that, I'll offer an alternative using absolute positioning:

```css
li{
  position:relative;
}
span{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>TEST TEXT <span>✘</span></li>
  <li>TEST TEXT <span>✔</span></li>
  <li>TEST TEXT TEST TEXT TEST TEXT<span>✘</span></li>
  <li>TEST TEXT TEST TEXT<span>✔</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also convert the list to a table and spread the table across either the page or container with and set the td with the tick or cross with the `text-align: right` element